# How to calculate the scale, rotation angle and translation between 2 images if we know the homography result matrix?result

Tags: image-processing, opencv, matrix, homography

I got the result of findHomorgraphy in OpenCv. As below:

Homography transform matrix: 
[-1.1534205416542787    0.7834287271121142      527.9064589440736
-0.2415444621693116     0.16412191792642924     110.54458949396778
-0.002184845612886825   0.0014838718631386306   1.0 ]

I dont know how to calculate the rotation angle, scale, translation betwwen 2 iamges?
Could you please show me how to calculate these parameters?

Comment: [-1.15 0.78 527.90; -0.24 0.16 110.54; -0.002 0.001 1.0 ]

Comment: Please look at link for rotation and scale http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28726/find-translation-rotation-and-scale-values-from-parameters-of-homography-matrix